# Remove iframe script tag using ONLY JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an auto-generated iframe (Which also have a class name and on the same domain), inside it, there is also a `<script>` tag and some styling. Can anyone tell me how to remove the script tag and its contents using pure javascript? [**NO jQuery** please, Using VueJS ]

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="#" class="myiframe">
        #document
        <html>
            <body>

                <!-- REMOVE-->
                <style>...</style>
                <!-- REMOVE-->

                <div class="wrapper">...</div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I know how to select the script tag (Might not perfect for the purpose), What I don't know is how to select the style tag which is inside of an iframe:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("style"), index;

for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
}
```

Comment: @Code_Ninja Possible with JQuery, I've seen Q & A on StackOverflow. Why not with Javascripts ?

Comment: yes I have just got an approach, let try and share you the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the following code, this code might be lengthy, lets try and optimize that:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script>
      function removeStyleTag() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
        var styleTag = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("style");

        for (var index = styleTag.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
          styleTag[index].parentNode.removeChild(styleTag[index]);
        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe id="myFrame" src="#" class="myiframe">
        #document
        <html>
            <body>

                <!-- REMOVE-->
                <style>...</style>
                <!-- REMOVE-->

                <div class="wrapper">...</div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
    <button onclick="removeStyleTag()">Try It</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

I have found a reference from [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_element_iframe).

I have just added the following 2 lines in addition to the code that you have written:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var styleTag = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("style");
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gbLkrm0x/) is a link to Fiddle where I have tried this code.

Comment: Awesome, It worked. Anyhow the iframe doesn't had a ID, I used `getElementsByClassName("myiframe")[0]` and it worked! 

Any way to optimize it since this iframe only contain one style tag (Select the first, maybe?)

Comment: It doesn't work for me, your `styleTag` is an empty `HTMLCollection`.

Comment: @Armel, if you are trying to use it here on stackoverflow, this error would come up, because I guess that stackoverflow restricts external source to run iFrame here. But try this in fiddle, and it will work.

Comment: @stackminu, yes that can be the thing, it will be converted into a generic code, but the code length would increase, can do that.. that's a good option

Comment: @Armel, stackoverflow converts the iFrame into text written in quotes (`"`), that's why you get that error.

Comment: @Code_Ninja I am trying in your Fiddle, weird :)

Comment: @Armel, run the script again, and then click on `Try It`, then everything will follow

Comment: Nope :/ `styleTag` keeps being empty for me.

Comment: Try this in incognito or clear cache, can be due to that, works for me and @stackminu everytime